# Update Text() based on user input in a TextFormField() within a container in a ListVIew

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview, flutter-text

I'm new to flutter and have a ... challenge with the above.

I retrive data about several objects / documents from FireStore and create a ListView.

The logic, or lack there of, look like this:

```
Container
    StreamBuilder
         ListView
             Container
                 Rows, Columns, Text and whatever to display each document from StreamBuilder.
```

This ListView contains several Containers where each Container display data from one object. Within each Container there is a TextFormField that takes a double. Based on this value, I want to change a Text() within the same container - a calculation.

Is this possible? If so - how? I understand I can use TextEditController somehow, but then the result of tha calculation will be editable. Or?

```
return new ListView(//
  children: getMedicationItem(asyncSnapshot
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: asyncSnapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
      MyObject object = new MyObject(document, integerValue);
      backgroundColor = !backgroundColor;
      return new Container(
        color: backgroundColor? Colors.black26: Colors.white,
          child: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Flexible(
                child: TextFormField(
                  onChanged: (text) {
                    double calculation = 0.0;
                    if (text.length > 0)
                      calculation = double.tryParse(text) * 23;
                    **UPDATE "$calculation" in Text() below** 
                  },
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  inputFormatters: [_decimal_validator],
                )
              ),
              new Flexible(
                child: Text("$calculation"),
              )
            ]
          ),
        );
      }
    ).toList(),
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need to do is use a `setState` to tell Flutter that the variable has changed and you want whichever Widgets that use it rebuilt:

```
if (text.length > 0){
  setState((){
    calculation = double.tryParse(text) * 23;
  });
}
```

Comment: I've been a little bit to eager to cut my code in the question. The ListView is within a StreamBuilder. And won't calling setState() redraw the whole StreamBuilder that contains the ListView? Each Container has an unique object that has different values that should be calculated based on what is typed in the TextFormField and change only the Text($calculation) within that Container.

Comment: You would need to have a variable for each of the results you want, or a List<String> with each of them, and update the one you need. This will trigger the rebuild of the view. You shouldn't have to worry about the performance. Unless you have a huge view, you should be fine.

Comment: I've solved this by using a List<double>, but when the widget get redrawn, the list of objects get redownloaded / read from firestore. This must be producing a lot of traffic between my app and firestor and with several users doing this a lot, the amount read would be great. That is an other ... challange. Thanks.

Comment: @user1086500 if the Answer fixed your issue, please mark it as correct, so that other users can find it too. Consider also upvoting for relevance.